# OPENXML question for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am brand new to OPENXML, and have 90 % of what I want to do working...stuck on this:

```
<ReportHost name="411.114.42.42">
  <HostProperties>
    <tag name="HOST_END">Wed Nov 11 20:48:43 2015</tag>
    <tag name="LastAuthenticatedResults">8675309</tag>
    <tag name="Credentialed_Scan">true</tag>
    <tag name="policy-used">AWT v6</tag>
    <tag name="ssh-auth-meth">MyPassword</tag>
    <tag name="ssh-login-used">MyLogin</tag>
    <tag name="local-checks-proto">ssh</tag>
    <tag name="host-ip">411.114.42.42</tag>
    <tag name="HOST_START">Wed Nov 11 20:00:01 2015</tag>
  </HostProperties>
</ReportHost>
```

My Desired results:

```
Wed Nov 11 20:48:43 2015
8675309
TRUE
AWT v6
MyPassword
MyLogin
ssh
411.114.42.42
Wed Nov 11 20:00:01 2015
```

I am able to get the name value ("Host_end", etc.), but not the content.

My query:

```
Select   * 
from OPENXML (@hdoc,'/ReportHost/HostProperties/tag',1)
WITH (
    name varchar (500)
     )
```

I'd like to stick with OPENXML if at all possible, since I just spent the day learning it and getting to this final step.

Please let me know if I have provided enough info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to query for `nodetype` 3 to get the element text. I have changed your `xpath` expression slightly so it just returns the node text

```
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @XmlDocument
Select   [text]
from OPENXML (@hdoc,'/ReportHost/HostProperties/tag/text()',3)
```

Comment: Thanks Jaco!   I had to put square brackets around [text] due to reserved word issues, but I got my desired results.   The help is much appreciated!

Comment: I added the square brackets in my answer, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

[OPENXML (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Extend the `SchemaDeclaration` with a `ColPattern` to specify a different XPath than what you get from the default behaviour of `ColName`.

```
declare @X xml = '
<ReportHost name="411.114.42.42">
  <HostProperties>
    <tag name="HOST_END">Wed Nov <B>11</B> 20:48:43 2015</tag>
    <tag name="LastAuthenticatedResults">8675309</tag>
    <tag name="Credentialed_Scan">true</tag>
    <tag name="policy-used">AWT v6</tag>
    <tag name="ssh-auth-meth">MyPassword</tag>
    <tag name="ssh-login-used">MyLogin</tag>
    <tag name="local-checks-proto">ssh</tag>
    <tag name="host-ip">411.114.42.42</tag>
    <tag name="HOST_START">Wed Nov 11 20:00:01 2015</tag>
  </HostProperties>
</ReportHost>';

declare @hdoc int;

exec sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc out, @X;

select T.Name,
       T.Value
from openxml(@hdoc, '/ReportHost/HostProperties/tag')
  with (
       Name varchar(500) '@name',
       Value varchar(500) '.'
       ) as T;

exec sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc;
```

You are shredding on the `tag` node so `.` specifies the current node value and and if you use `@` to specify that you want an attribute you don't have to care about the `flags` parameter to `OPENXML`.

> I'd like to stick with OPENXML if at all possible, since I just spent
>   the day learning it and getting to this final step.

I would recommend you to spend some time with the [XML data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx) instead. The same query in that case would look like this.

```
declare @X xml = '
<ReportHost name="411.114.42.42">
  <HostProperties>
    <tag name="HOST_END">Wed Nov <B>11</B> 20:48:43 2015</tag>
    <tag name="LastAuthenticatedResults">8675309</tag>
    <tag name="Credentialed_Scan">true</tag>
    <tag name="policy-used">AWT v6</tag>
    <tag name="ssh-auth-meth">MyPassword</tag>
    <tag name="ssh-login-used">MyLogin</tag>
    <tag name="local-checks-proto">ssh</tag>
    <tag name="host-ip">411.114.42.42</tag>
    <tag name="HOST_START">Wed Nov 11 20:00:01 2015</tag>
  </HostProperties>
</ReportHost>';

select T.X.value('@name', 'varchar(500)') as Name,
       T.X.value('.', 'varchar(500)') as Value
from @X.nodes('/ReportHost/HostProperties/tag') as T(X);
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra option Mikael.  I will check both of these out today side by side.  As you can imagine, there is quite a bit more going on here.  The XML I provided was just a snippet of a much larger document...in reality, there could be one to thousands of HostProperty segments...and I have no control of the incoming data :)